# XJC Multi files already defined error when there's no duplicated type

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I'm using xjc command to compile some XSD files and generate the classes for me. But I'm having an weird issue.
When I compile passing only one file to it, it compiles fine. But when I pass the dir to compile everything it says that a type is already defined. And it says both of the types are in the same file. When I go to the lines specified, I see that the names of the types are completely diferent (and it says every single type in the xsd file is already defined and it points the other definition to the same file). I've searched all the files to see if the type exists somewhere else and I didn't find a single one duplicated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out there was other file including the same XSD making it colide with itself.